# Social media icons - open an app, not a website

Tags: joomla

We have experimented with some modules to display social media icons on our Joomla site and to link to the social media site. When the used clicks on the icon it is taken to the website. Assuming the user is on a mobile device, is there a way of going directly to the App, instead of the website?

Answer (score 0):

The modules which you used to dsiplay the social icons should be display automatcially in mobile website, or you need to check that it should not be display: noe for media Query. Provide you domain url to check this.